# Facebook ID or Cognito ID or Alternative for my iPhone application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-cognito

I am currently uniquely identifying a user by storing the FacebookID of that user. I recently read around and I saw that this is incorrect usage and that Facebook ID's can change for some reason, all in all that I shouldn't use them. Is this true? If so, is a AWS Cognito ID that is derived when a new facebook user signs in and authenticates themselves a viable way to uniquely identify a user? If not, How would I uniquely link a facebook account, with apparently no variable that is stable enough to store, with a unique identifier to store in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following statement (from the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading):

> No matter what version they originally used to sign up for your app, the ID will remain the same for people who have already logged into your app. This change is backwards-compatible for anyone who has logged into your app at any point in the past.

So, you can use the Facebook ID to uniquely identify your users.

However, depending on your use case and the way you plan to manage security, you should consider a few more things. The purpose of AWS Cognito ID is not to be communicated between users, it is kept between your app and Cognito. So if you want users to communicate using their accounts (sending text messages for example), the Facebook ID is more suited for that. Nevertheless, I am experiencing [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219708/fine-grained-access-control-for-aws-dynamodb-using-aws-cognito) when trying to achieve fine-grained access control using DynamoDB.

Comment: So are you saying that I can use the facebook ID as a means of uniquely identifying a user?

Comment: @user2977578, you misunderstood that, Facebook id varies from app to app for a single user, but within a single app it always remain the same. As Hatim said, you can surely use Facebook ids to identify your users.

Answer (score 0):

As Hatim said, the Cognito identity id is not meant to be shared between users.

That being said, once an identity id has a login associated to it, it could only change on merging with another authenticated id. Unless you're doing that, which it doesn't sound like you are, it would be a stable way to identify your users. You could use the identity id as the identifier in your database, as long as it isn't exposed.

If you're using DynamoDB, as [this blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies%20%22this%20blog%20post) explains, doing it this way allows you to configure your IAM roles to make access to this data more secure.